# rsync cannot write files to folders it created

Tags: ftp, rsync, ntfs, rsnapshot, curlftpfs

As the title says, Rsync is not able to copy files to the folders that Rsync itself created seconds before. I thought it could be a problem with `curlftpfs`, which is what mounts the ftp folder.

I tried to create a file inside a folder that contains a name with a dot, like `daily.0` in `touch /mnt/ftp/.../daily.0/test.txt` I can create it.

When I use a editor as `nano` the following message `[ Error writing lock file /mnt/ftp/.../daily.0/.test.txt.swp: Operation not supported ]` appears, but it creates it. If I use an editor like `vi` the terminal freezes.

If I create folders, copy or move files there is no problem.

### I leave you some additional information:

#### curlftpfs

```
curlftpfs -o utf8 -o allow_other ${FTP_USER}:${FTP_PASSWD}@${FTP_HOST} /mnt/ftp -v; grep -qs '/mnt/ftp ' /proc/mounts
```

It is tested with rsync 3.1.2 and 3.2.7. I have also tried using only rsync and it is not able to create the files either.

#### rsnapshot (part of rsnapshot_ftp.conf)

```
rsync_long_args --delete --delete-excluded --no-owner --no-group --no-perms --no-times --modify-window=3602
backup  /persistence/backups/tmp/               ./
```

**Ouput to rsnapshot:** `/usr/bin/rsnapshot -c /etc/rsnapshot_ftp.conf daily;`

```
require Lchown
Lchown module loaded successfully
Setting locale to POSIX "C"
echo 6659 > /var/run/rsnapshot.pid
mkdir -m 0700 -p /mnt/ftp/...
...
mkdir -m 0755 -p /mnt/ftp/.../daily.0/
/usr/bin/rsync -av --delete /persistence/backups/tmp/ /mnt/ftp/.../daily.0/./
rsync: mkstemp "/mnt/ftp/.../daily.0/.backup_to_ftp.tar.lmLoNR" failed: Operation not supported (95)
rsync: mkstemp "/mnt/ftp/.../daily.0/.backup2_to_ftp.tar.lmJrSC" failed: Operation not supported (95)

sent 604,429,298 bytes  received 2,640 bytes  172,694,839.43 bytes/sec
total size is 604,280,067  speedup is 1.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1205) [sender=3.1.3]
WARNING: Some files and/or directories in /persistence/backups/tmp/ only transferred partially during rsync operation
/usr/bin/logger -p user.err -t rsnapshot[6659] WARNING: Some files and/or \
    directories in /persistence/backups/tmp/ only transferred partially \
    during rsync operation
touch /mnt/ftp/.../daily.0/
rm -f /var/run/rsnapshot.pid
/usr/bin/logger -p user.err -t rsnapshot[6659] WARNING: /usr/bin/rsnapshot \
    -c /etc/rsnapshot_ftp.conf daily: completed, but with some warnings
```

#### The same thing that rsnapshot does but in rsync commands (+/-):

`mkdir -m 0755 -p /mnt/ftp/.../daily.0/`

`/usr/local/bin/rsync -va --delete --numeric-ids --delete-excluded /persistence/backups/tmp/ /mnt/ftp/.../daily.0/./`

````
...
rsync: [receiver] mkstemp "/mnt/ftp/.../daily.0/.backup_to_ftp.tar.1HGJ8m" failed: Operation not supported (95)```
...
sent 603,661,017 bytes  received 393 bytes  241,464,564.00 bytes/sec
total size is 603,512,067  speedup is 1.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1336) [sender=3.2.7]
````

### Any help is welcome!

I've spent many hours and I'm starting to think that `rsync` in `ext4` is not capable of working on `curlftpfs` with `NTFS`...
Feel free to leave opinions on how to do something like rsnapshot without using rsync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is here:

> ```
> rsync: mkstemp "/mnt/ftp/.../daily.0/.backup_to_ftp.tar.lmLoNR" failed: Operation not supported (95)
> ```

It's telling you that the remote system - or one of the cludges used to access it - cannot handle the specified file name.

At a guess I would suggest that the remote system cannot handle filenames that start with a dot. You can test this easily enough yourself:

```
date >/mnt/ftp/…/.test
```

If this is the case, `rsync` has just the flag to workaround this broken behaviour, `--inplace`. There are disadvantages to using this option, which is why it's not the default (read `man rsync` for the details).

Now an opinion piece. Trying to run a backup generation directly across an FTP service seems fraught with unnecessary complexity. Are you aware that FTP (by default, at least) provides no transport level encryption and data is transferred in the clear across the network? Do your backups contain sensitive data? Do you test that these backups can be used for recovery?

Comment: Yes, I know. Using FTP is not the best idea, but it's what I have.
I also thought it would be a problem with hidden files, but no. If I run the command 'date >/mnt/ftp/…/.test' it works perfectly

Comment: What about `date > /mnt/ftp/.../.backup_to_ftp.tar.lmLoNR`?

Comment: It works well. The problem seems to be that it is when editing the files on the fly, as I said (something that vi does and not nano, for example...)

Comment: It is also possible that the server (where the FTP is located) is not capable of editing files on the fly and that causes rsync to die in the attempt. So the question is: Can I tell rsync not to edit files on the fly?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say "_edit files on the fly_". The `rsync` tool writes to a temporary file such as `.backup_to_ftp.tar.lmLoNR` and then renames it (in this case) to `backup_to_ftp.tar`, replacing an existing file if necessary. You could try the `rsync --inplace` option, which would create the target file directly rather than writing first to a temporary

Comment: Exact. The problem was that rsync tool writes to a temporary file. It is important to keep in mind that if you are working on the same file system you can use `--no-whole-file`.
When I read about '--inplace' I misunderstood and...
Sorry for the inconvenience. Here is your +1